# tgz file give invalid compressed data--format violated

Tags: tar, gzip

I have download this file

```
http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/55.1/icu4c-55_1-HPUX11iv3-aCC.tgz
https://ssl.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/55.1/icu4c-bin-55_1.md5
```

md5sum ok

But on linux and hpux 11.31 give me this error,i have put
various commands

```
gunzip icu4c-55_1-HPUX11iv3-aCC.tgz 

gunzip: icu4c-55_1-HPUX11iv3-aCC.tgz: invalid compressed data--format violated

gunzip -d < icu4c-55_1-HPUX11iv3-aCC.tgz| tar xvf -

gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

tar -tvf icu4c-55_1-HPUX11iv3-aCC.tgz 

gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Although the file has a valid gzip header, what follows doesn't seem to be valid. There must have been some error when generating the file. You should contact the people who distribute the file and tell them that the file is invalid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a specific file that is corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: was a corrupted file on their server,md5 refer good because is referred to the corrupted file
I download an older release which works fine

Answer (score 7):

The steps highlighted at
https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/202392488-gpdbrestore-gp-restore-fails-with-gzip-stdin-invalid-compressed-data-format-violated-
fixed it for me:

```
wget http://www.gzip.org/fixgz.zip
unzip fixgz.zip
gcc -o fixgz fixgz.c
fixgz <corrupted_gzip_backup_file>.gz <fixed_gzip_backup_file>.gz
```

This is weird, given that the specific file you mentioned seems to
have the proper MD5 sum.

Comment: Nice find. The fact that the MD5 is valid only shows that the file wasn't corrupted between the point where the checksum was generated and our machines. The file was evidently corrupted between the point where it was generated (presumably on a HP-UX build machine) and the point where the checksum was generated (presumably on the distribution server where all the files are located).

Comment: @Gilles: That would explain it. Let's say that's not exactly the most useful way to generate checksums.